# ng-options for select box binding to hash

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I'm a little confused on how to do a binding with AngularJS.  I'm putting a <select> element in with an ng-model="variable.type".    I've also got a $scope.type variable with is a hash table.  The key of that hashtable is the variable.type.

So basically I want the select box to list all of the values from $scope.type, and then do the binding so that the variable.type is linked to the key of the hashtable.  I'm just not sure how to specify the ng-options to do that.

```
<tr ng-repeat="variable in variables">
    <td>
        <select ng-model="variable.type" ng-options="????">
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you add to question code for your hashtable

Comment: Some sample data or a jsfiddle would be nice.  Is `$scope.type` an object then and you want it's properties to be the options?  Is it an array?  What do you want to set variable.type to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, you're basically asking how to use an object as a data source for `ng-options`.  If `$scope.type` looks like this:

```
$scope.type = {
    "type1": { value: "value1" },
    "type2": { value: "value2" },
    "type3": { value: "value3" }
};
```

And $scope.variables looks like this:

```
$scope.variables = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "item1",
      type: "type1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "item2",
      type: "type2"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "item3",
      type: "type3"
    }
];
```

Then you could bind it up like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="variable in variables">
  <td>
    <select ng-model="variable.type" ng-options="key as vartype.value for (key, vartype) in type"></select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/INHfc160g6qF9fjszVaW?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, that ng-options string worked great for what I was trying to do!